# Testing Rails with Devise API using Postman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I currently have an API that has an association between a Devise user. I want to test my routes using Postman or curl, but I keep getting authentication issues. Is there any easy way to get around this to test the routes?

Comment: Hey OP, did you by any chance find the answer to your question? I have a similiar need :)

Comment: @MichaelVictor I completely forgot to reply and just remembered about it..hopefully this might help others out there. I used `curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/users -d "{\"user\":{\"email\":\"user@example.com\",\"password\":\"password\"}}"`

Answer (score 0):

in your `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` comment out the line

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```